# Change logging verbosity level for health check endpoint in ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, health-monitoring

I have an ASP.NET Core application (.NET 5 actually) and it has health check endpoints implemented in a standard way with

```
services.AddHealthChecks()...
```

Health checks are working fine. The problem is they are being invoked quite often and hence they generate a lot of logs in our storage.

Service has standard .NET logging mechanisms and defaults in appsettings.json like

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Microsoft": "Debug",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Debug"
    }
  },
```

The question is how can I change verbosity level (to `Information`, for example) for this very heath check (and its implementation inside also, like EF.Core stuff or anything else) while keeping it as `Debug` in all other places?
Are there any parameters or settings to help with this?

The goal here is to reduce logging storage consumption.

Comment: Do you see the LogLevel element in your config? What namespace does the health check log with? Have you tried adding it there, with a configured minimum level of, say, "Information"? At https://github.com/Xabaril/AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks/blob/50594f0643515e83f9bf6ce864f9594bf980b865/samples/HealthChecks.UI.Branding/appsettings.json (a random file from the repository found through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-5.0)) it looks like its logging namespace is "HealthChecks".

Comment: @CodeCaster Disabling logging for namespaces will disable them in all other places too, not only in healthcheck specific "call stack". If I got it right. Also, HealthChecks=None in configs can only disable specific healthcheck stuff, not all other things like database access procedures that are used inside healthcheck.

Comment: Ah, you mean that the health check may execute a query which in turn triggers SQL debug logging on its own logger name? Perhaps some example logs would have clarified that.

Comment: These logs usually look like `dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20000] Opening connection to database 'some_db' on server 'tcp://localhost:5432'.`

Comment: I made an edit to my post @AndrewSilver, It migth not be the ideal soultion for you but its a solution.

Answer (score 2):

In the settings file:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Microsoft": "Debug",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Debug"
  }
},
```

You can configure the LogLevel on the namespace level by specifiying `"namespace":"LogLevel"` inside the `LogLevel` configuration object.

For instance:

You're seeing lots of `dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20000] Opening connection to database 'some_db' on server 'tcp://localhost:5432'` messages.

As you can tell by the line itself, they're coming from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection` object, inside `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database` namespace.

So you could modify the LogLevel for `Microsoft`, or `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` or even `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database` namespace to be `Information` for instance:

```
"Logging": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Debug",
    "Microsoft": "Debug",
    "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Debug",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database": "Information"
  }
},
```

Now the line `dbug: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20000] Opening connection to database 'some_db' on server 'tcp://localhost:5432'` won't get logged because its level is `Debug` and the minimum threshold is configured to be `Information`.

**EDIT**

It looks like you're trying to filter based on the context of the request instead of using just the namespace.

AFAIK, aspnetcore logging package is not capable of doing that.
On the other hand, [Serilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog) with a little aid from [Serilog.Expressions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions) can filter out the log messages when they originated from specific requests.

From Serilog.Expressions readme file:

> **Filtering example**
>
> Serilog.Expressions adds ByExcluding() and ByIncludingOnly() overloads to the Filter configuration object that accept filter expressions:
>
> ```
> Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
>  .Filter.ByExcluding("RequestPath like '/health%'")
>  .CreateLogger();
> ```

Comment: As I believe from the comments, they _do_ want `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database` debug logging, _except_ when logged from the HealthCheck module.

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks, exactly. Just imagine this situation. There are a lot of calls of healthchecks endpoints with a lot of logs being written from *healthcheck*. These records are very repetitive and not very useful here. But they can be useful in other places

Comment: Thank you for your edit Pablo. Yeah, I know Serilog is capable of this, I've seen some articles about it before. But I'm looking for similar implementations using standard .NET Core logging mechanisms

Comment: Best way is to change the logger based on the url in the request context.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this with a combination of:

1. @Pablo Recalde's changes to the appsettings.json (to filter out specific logs > Warning produced regularly by certain librarys)
2. Where normal app service code is called (that will be used in regular calling paths), use a NullLogger:

Note: Logically, this doesn't stop all logging paths + is a bit *whack-a-mole* but works to remove the majority of the logs produced during 'normal/success' health check scenarios.

implementation:
1.:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Identity": "Warning"
    },
    "AzureAppServicesFile": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Identity": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "AzureAppServicesBlob": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Identity": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
```

2. 

```
    public async Task MyFunctionName(bool useNullLogger) {

        if (useNullLogger)
        {
            _logger = new NullLogger<MyClassName>();
        }
...
}
```